# Pasting text to a new buffer

Tags: vim, neovim

I've found questions that are *similar*, but don't really address what I'm trying to learn.  I want to yank or delete text and append it to a new (or existing) buffer *without* *changing* buffers.  I want to basically redirect the pasted text to its destination at the end of a separate buffer without leaving the original one, similar to what you might do with shell file redirection.  I have a hard time believing vim/nvim can't do this, but haven't found an appropriate answer anywhere as of yet.

```
:'a, 'bw ~/path/to/file.txt
```

This will copy the text between the two marks 'a and 'b, and write it to a file in the filesystem.  This is good, but the file can't be appended to... and it doesn't get opened in a buffer.

Comment: You can use `appendbufline()`, but, in fact, your question looks very much as [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Generally, one needs to change text in a non-active buffer only while doing some "advanced" scripting. Otherwise, it makes sense _to do change_ an active buffer first, do an editing task and then just get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* a `:w >> {file}` variant that lets you append to a file ([`:help :write_a`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Awrite_a)).

As @Matt already commented, the usual way would involve switching buffers. Vimscript usage is closely aligned with (mostly Ex-) commands that the user would interactively use. With recent Vim versions, you can alternatively call the low-level [`appendbufline()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#appendbufline%28%29) function, though. This would bypass any autocmds, buffer setttings, etc. Depending on your use case, this can be desirable or not.

If the target buffer is already visible or can be kept visible as a side effect, temporarily switching to it is easy (mostly involving [`:sbuffer`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Asbuffer)). My [ingo-library plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) has a function [`ingo#buffer#visible#Execute()`](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ingo-library/blob/ed53ce9b33f511a70b6666b3eb0959ab7aafb702/autoload/ingo/buffer/visible.vim#L27) that also handles hidden buffers transparently.